# If $J$ is an ideal of $R$ that is maximal in the set of ideals of $R$ that annihilate elements of $R/I$, then $J$ is a prime ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Show that if $J$ is an ideal of $R$ that is maximal in the set of ideals of $R$ that annihilate elements of $R/I$, then $J$ is a prime ideal of $R$.

I've tried to show that J is prime directly by supposing that $ab\in J$. Without loss of generality suppose that $b\notin J$. Now let $\overline{i}\in R/I$. Then $ab\overline{i}=0$ in $R/I$... not sure where to go from here... need maximality of $J$.

Comment: For rings with identity, $(R/I)J=\{0+I\}$ implies $J=RJ\subseteq I$. Therefore the maximal ideal annihilating $R/I$ is $I$ itself, and it need not be prime.  So the problem statement is fishy, as written.  I don't even believe it if you assume the ring has no identity, because it doesn't work when you do have an identity.

Comment: Ah, does it mean that $J$ is maximal in the set of $\{ann(x+I)\mid x\in R\}$? Because it's ambiguous...

Comment: @rschwieb I would assume that's what it means.

Comment: Noncommutative rings? If so, are you aware that you are not using the normal definition of "prime" for noncommutative rings? is that intentional? Or commutative rings after all since you didn't specify a side for the annihilator?

Comment: @rschwieb, again im gonna assume that dragonite means commutative rings, since theres no specification.

Comment: @Gengar That's nice.  The point is to help the person write better questions, though, not for me to get blind speculation.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming commutative rings with identity, since so much is up in the air without it*

---

Suppose $J=ann(x+I)$ is maximal among other point annihilators of elements in $R/I$. Suppose $ab\in J$ but $b\notin J$.

It follows that $b$ does not annihilate $x+I$, for if it did, $bR+J$ would also annihilate $x+I$ and would properly contain $J$ and contradict its maximality.

But $a\in ann(bx+I)$, since $abx\in I$.

Now note that $ann(x+I)\subseteq ann(bx+I)$.  Can you finish from here?